# Template substitution error with initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

I know how to make the following code work : I just to uncomment the second constructor of Printer.

The idea is simple : I want to write a constructor / function that can take several arguments stored in some abract data structure that I can iterate. I want it to work at least with vectors and lists (it does) but also with initializer list (and it doesn't).

I use the following simple syntax (maybe a bit more generic than I would like, I don't use template templates) so I don't have to write a variadic template in order to handle the allocator types of std::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

struct Printer
{
    template<class Container>
    Printer(const Container& cont)
    {
        for(const auto & e : cont)
            cout << e << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    //template<class T>
    //Printer(const initializer_list<T> & l)//why should I ?
    //{
    //  for(const T & e : l)
    //      cout << e << " ";
    //  cout << endl;
    //}
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    Printer pv(v);
    Printer pv2 = v; //ok : not explicit

    list<char> l = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    Printer pl(l);
    Printer pl2 = l; //ok : not explicit

    Printer pi1 = {4,5,6};      
    Printer pi2 ({4,5,6}); //same as above if explicit      
}
```

But why should I explicitely write a specific constructor for initializer list ? The error is "could not convert ‘{4, 5, 6}’ from ‘’ to ‘Printer’".

Basically, what it tells is that the substitution does not work with the initializer list. But why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initializer\_list and template type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction)

Comment: The post says "because the standard says so". I find it rather unsatisfying. I would like to know why. I'm not sure I understand why substitution fails

Comment: `{}` is never deduced to an `initializer_list` when passed to a template function (other than `auto`). you have to exclicitly provide the type, the compiler doesn't know you want an `initializer_list`. this is the standard, so there is no other answer. Never pass `{}` to a function with template arguments, it will never compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *brace-enclosed initializer list* (formally, *braced-init-list*) is not a `std::initializer_list`. It can be converted to one, but it isn't one. It's also not a container type. It's not a type at all, actually, it's a grammatical construct consisting of either the following sequences of symbols:

> { initializer-list ,<sub>opt</sub> }
>
> { }

Therefore this syntax will not work outright:

```
Printer pi1 = {4,5,6};      
Printer pi2 ({4,5,6}); //same as above if explicit
```

If `Printer` was an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), then it could perform aggregate initialization.

Otherwise, you're kind of stuck accepting a `std::initializer_list` that can be constructed from the *brace-enclosed iniitalizer list* you've provided.

---

More info:

What you're actually doing with that syntax is called *list-initialization*, (aggregate initialization is a type of list-initialization). Just to confuse things further, when used to initialize a type like `T{a, b, c, ...}` it's called an *initializer list*. This is not to be confused with a `std::initializer_list`.

When `std::initializer_list` was added in C++11, it got special treatment. A *braced-init-list* could now be used to construct a temporary `std::initializer_list` in a constructor. This is where you saw us suddenly able to create a `std::vector<int>` so easily as `std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...};`

However, one thing to be wary of is that `std::initializer_list` constructors are "high priority" constructors that the compiler will choose [when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074071/why-is-this-initializer-list-constructor-a-viable-overload) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613660/27678) [least](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47608388/27678) [suspect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19481508/27678).

Comment: Ok, I understand. It's still "because the standard says so", but at least now I know why. I guess I'll just look into aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Printer pi1 = {4,5,6};      
Printer pi2 ({4,5,6}); //same as above if explicit
```

by something like

```
Printer pi1 = vector<int>{4,5,6};      
Printer pi2 (vector<int>{4,5,6}); //same as above if explicit
```

Comment: No. I think I expalined wrongly what I want. I want the syntax written in my mai to work as it is written. I simply don't understand why the template code fails to work.

Comment: The post says "because the standard says so". I find it rather unsatisfying. I would like to know why

Comment: @R.Absil `error: could not convert ‘{4, 5, 6}’ from ‘’ to ‘Printer’` is not just unsatisfying ^^ How the compiler can guess what is the Container if you do not say ?

Comment: Well, it does it with a vector, I would assume that anything pack within {} is initializer_list, no ?